# need a delay between 2 function each has set time out

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, settimeout, intervals

I have 2 functions abc() and def(). both are having settimeout function. they are called from parent xyz() function. Initially abc() should be called then after the abc animation def() functionality should be invoked. Problem: Both the functions are called one after the other but there is no delay between them.both the settimeout are working simultaneously. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
function abc() {
    // there is settimeout function
    //cleartimeout after some time 
}

function def() {
    // there is settimeout function
    //cleartimeout after some time 
}

function xyz() {
    abc(); // i need a delay between each settimeout functionality. 
    def(); //currently both run together.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do the timeout in `xyz()`

```
function abc() {
    // Leave this alone, no need for setTimeout in here
}

function def() {
    // Leave this alone, no need for setTimeout in here
}

function xyz() {
    abc(); // i need a delay between each setTimeout functionality. 
    setTimeout(def, 500);
}
```

If `def()` **ALWAYS** comes after `abc()` then you can have `xyz()` simply call `abc()` and within `abc()` you can call `def()` after the animation finishes but we would need to see the code for `abc()` =)